# TypeScript React: Use an array of strings as an index and get values from state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface PropsInterface {
  keys: string; // name,email,password
}

const Poster: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: 'jim',
    email: 'jim@gmaail.com',
    password: 'secret',
    loading: false,
    keys: props.keys.split(','),  // [ name, email, password ]
  });
  const { keys } = state;
```

I need to somehow get the values for each of the keys and form a string that will end up looking like this

```
"name=jim&email=jim@gmaail.com&password=secret"
```

I thought I could simply use `URLSearchParams()` that quickly became a problem with TypeScript. My next thought was to loop over the keys and then get the corresponding values from the state

```
    for (const i in keys) {
      if (keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(state[keys[i]]);
      }
    }
```

which then gives me the error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ auth: boolean; baseUrl: string; keys: string[]; method: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ auth: boolean; baseUrl: string; keys: string[]; method: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: Is the type it's complaining about the type of your state? (It has property names your state doesn't have, but I wonder if you've cut your state down for the purposes of the question...)

Comment: yes I simplified it to make it easy to read

Comment: Fundamentally, when you do `state[keys[i]]`, you're using a string to index into `state`. If your state object's type doesn't have an index signature, TypeScript won't let you do that (without a type assertion)...

Comment: ok, how to make an assertion that will make TypeScript happy about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, when you do `state[keys[i]]`, you're using a string to index into `state`. If your state object's type doesn't have an index signature, TypeScript won't let you do that (without a type assertion)...

You can use a local type assertion, perhaps with an alias variable, instead:

```
const rawState = state as any as Record<string, string>;
for (const key of keys) {
    console.log(rawState[key]);
}
```

(Also note using `for-of` to loop the array.)

Of course, that's disabling type checking for that loop...

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOBJcaeJZAbwChlkBrCATxwC5kcwpQBzAbmQHpfkIOAFsIAGgjC4wADZiscHDgDuGKABNyAX3LkEGEKxZg4kZAF4ylKoJERmAcgBWwYQ7HWqk6TMcvhAAIcUj4AdPpuHjbICkqqGo44EAhQEGDunsgyGHDqnMzwMklRNrQMzABEQqISUrLyiipq6hWhOFgywGAAFO4OAJRiVPzIANq2Ncje9TGN8erIALraXLr6hmBkNPQ4yFoWxqYQq+tGUHDKAMomZpasR8iKjyB0j7sASsnNADys7CAcIZ-TgAPlWMDUyG6p02ZWQGBgVDKOH6VmipwwMggoWyHG65yuNwgozKi36qy0QA)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it's maybe your solution to solve the problem.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface PropsInterface {
  keys: string; // name,email,password
}

const Poster: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: 'jim',
    email: 'jim@gmaail.com',
    password: 'secret',
    loading: false,
    keys: props.keys.split(','),  // [ name, email, password ]
  });
  const pairKeys = React.useMemo<string>(() => {
    const order = ["name", "email", "password"];
    const result: string[] = [];

    state.keys.forEach((key: string, index) => {
      result.push(`${order[index]}=${state[order[index]]}`)
    });

    return result.join("&")
  }, [state.keys])

  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(pairKeys, null, 2)}</div>
  )
}



render(<Poster keys="John,test@test.com,testpass" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```